# Geographic Information Retrieval dataset

Tags: data-request, geospatial

Where can I find some datasets for Geographical Information Retrieval? I tried to search for GeoCLEF, but the whole dataset is no more available. Moreover, some geo-tagget tweets do not usually contain geographical keywords, so we have geographic coordinates for test values with no textual content to be retrieved.

Moreover, I found the "Mapping the lakes" dataset, but even though it is organized as a gazzetter associating to each word its geographical coordinates, there are no full-text queries over which I can benchmark by retrieval system.

I've been searching for a long time for such dataset, but I was not able to find what I need.

Do you know where can I find some GIR dataset?